# Como aplicar ação recursiva no csv.DictReader

Tags: python, csv

Olá, criei o seguinte código mas ele só aplica a função de criar o arquivo txt usando o último registro da tabela CSV, como consigo fazer para que ele crie um arquivo pra cada registro dessa tabela?

```
import csv
import os
with open('lista.csv') as listacsv:
leitor = csv.DictReader(listacsv)
for row in leitor:
    a = row['nome']
    b = row['empresa']

os.mknod("{}_{}.txt".format(a,b))
```

Segue o arquivo CSV de exemplo:

```
nome,empresa,logo
Diego Rocha,Espaço Rocha,espacorocha.png
Adiana Bonfim,Bonfim Select,bonfim.png
Cris Matarazzo,Spazio Odontologia,spazio.png
```

Comment: Cada arquivo com uma linha: `Diego Rocha,Espaço Rocha,espacorocha.png` num arquivo, noutro arquivo `Adiana Bonfim,Bonfim Select,bonfim.png` etc.. É isso? E o nome dos arquivos?

Answer (score 0):

Você chegou bem perto de resolver o problema, porém, faltou atenção em relação a [indentação](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/Conceitos_b%C3%A1sicos/Indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Em Python isso é crucial e delimita os blocos do código.

Segue uma solução:

```
import csv
import os

with open('lista.csv') as listacsv:
    leitor = csv.DictReader(listacsv)
    for row in leitor:
        a = row['nome']
        b = row['empresa']
        nome = "{}_{}.txt".format(a,b).replace(" ","_")
        os.mknod(nome);
```

Arquivos Gravados:

```
Adiana_Bonfim_Bonfim_Select.txt
Cris_Matarazzo_Spazio_Odontologia.txt
Diego_Rocha_Espaço_Rocha.txt
```

Comment: Amigo, você não faz ideia do quanto me ajudou com essa informação. muito obrigado mesmo pela sua ajuda!!